# "The requested address is not valid in its context" when running kubeproxy usermode in Windows

Tags: windows, kubernetes

I'm trying to connect a Windows node to a Kubernetes cluster, but when running the kube-proxy in usermode I keep getting the error `The requested address is not valid in its context`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Answering this one myself because it was one of those little undocumeted gotchas when setting up a Windows node in a K8S cluster.

The code in netsh.go from the Kubernetes code base includes a function like this:

```
// GetInterfaceToAddIP returns the interface name where Service IP needs to be added
// IP Address needs to be added for netsh portproxy to redirect traffic
// Reads Environment variable INTERFACE_TO_ADD_SERVICE_IP, if it is not defined then "vEthernet (HNS Internal NIC)" is returned
func (runner *runner) GetInterfaceToAddIP() string {
    if iface := os.Getenv("INTERFACE_TO_ADD_SERVICE_IP"); len(iface) > 0 {
        return iface
    }
    return "vEthernet (HNS Internal NIC)"
}
```

This function says that proxied service IP addresses will be added to a NIC adapter called `vEthernet (HNS Internal NIC)` unless you specify the `INTERFACE_TO_ADD_SERVICE_IP` environment variable by calling `netsh interface ipv4 add address name="vEthernet (HNS Internal NIC)" address=10.100.0.10`. If `vEthernet (HNS Internal NIC)` doesn't exist (and it won't unless you have set it up yourself) then you get the `The requested address is not valid in its context` error.

Following the docs at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/kubernetes/getting-started-kubernetes-windows#preparing-a-windows-node results in a NIC called `vEthernet (cbr0)`, which can be used in the `INTERFACE_TO_ADD_SERVICE_IP` environment variable.